# Conditional Expectations

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose we roll fair die until we obtain a score of $6$. Let $Y$ denote the number of rolls and let $X$ denote the number of rolls on which we get a score of $1$.

I have to find $\mathbb{E}[X]$ and $\mathbb{E}[X^2|Y]$.

I started as:

$Y$ follows a geometric distibution with $p=\frac16$ so that for $y=1,2,3,\ldots$
$$\mathbb{P}(Y=y)=\frac16 \left(\frac56 \right)^{y-1}.$$

$X|Y$ follows a binomial distribution such that for $x=1,2,\ldots,y-1,$
$$\mathbb{P}(X=x|Y=y)=  {y-1 \choose x}\left(\frac15\right)^x \left(\frac45 \right)^{y-1-x}.$$

Then $\mathbb{E}[X]= \sum_{y=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{E}[X|Y=y]\mathbb{P}[Y=y],$ where
$$\mathbb{E}[X|Y=y]=\sum_{x=1}^{y-1} x{y-1 \choose x}\left(\frac15\right)^x \left(\frac45 \right)^{y-1-x}. $$

This simplifies to
$$ \mathbb{E}[X|Y=y]=\left(\frac45 \right)^{y-1} \sum_{x=1}^{y-1} x{y-1 \choose x}\left(\frac14\right)^x,$$
but I can't proceed from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I have to solve the question using conditional expectations. Here's what I did.

$X|Y=y$ follows a binomial distribution with mean $\frac{y-1}{5}$ and variance $\frac{4(y-1)}{25}$.

So we have $\mathbb{E}[X|Y=y]=\frac{y-1}{5}$ so that

$$\mathbb{E}[X]=\frac16 \sum_{y=1}^{\infty} \frac{y-1}{5} \left(\frac56\right)^{y-1} = \frac{1}{30} \sum_{y=0}^{\infty} y\left(\frac56 \right)^y $$.

Since
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n(a^n) = \dfrac{a}{(1-a)^2},$$
we find that $\mathbb{E}[X]=1$.

As for $\mathbb{E}[X^2|Y]$, it is given by $ \text{Var}[X|Y] + \mathbb{E}^2[X|Y]$, which simplifies to
$$\frac{Y^2 + 2Y -3}{25}.$$

Answer (score 1):

There's a simpler way to get $E[X]$. All rolls that aren't $1$ or $6$ are irrelevant, and each roll that's $1$ or $6$ has a $50/50$ chance of being $1$ or $6$. Thus the expected number of $1$s is the expected number of heads before the first tails when repeatedly throwing a fair coin.